Is it important that my dishwasher's cabinet seals make contact with the opening?
I installed a new dishwasher that has rubber seals on the outside on three sides. If pushed back the appropriate amount they are just hanging in space.
The new one has rubber pieces that run along both sides and the top, I assume to help keep noise in the mounting cabinet. I pushed this into place as shown in the pictures to keep the rubber pieces in contact with the wood cabinet.
If I push it back an appropriate amount, i.e. further back into the cabinet to make the front flush, then the rubber has no contact. Essentially, the front piece of the cabinet touches when the dishwasher is too far out, but the cabinet sides are set further out once past the front piece.
Do I need to add new wood pieces here? Or, is this normal I I just should ignore what the rubber pieces are doing?
The mounting brackets are not in yet. I wanted to get position correct before installing.
Dishwasher, currently out too far; not flush:

Front view, showing rubber sides currently in contact with front of cabinet:

Dishwasher, showing sliver of gap that is along entire sides if pushed back further than shown here:


what do the instructions say

Don't beat yourself up.  Do you think quick installers are going to put as much care and thought into what you are doing?

If it's not too late to return this dishwasher, you could look into a panel-ready / built-in style model instead. They are designed to have their front flush with the cabinet. Some of them come with (or have an optional extra) stainless steel panel to make them look like a regular dishwasher, just flush with your cabinet doors.

Thank you for the very helpful comments. A couple notes on this: (1) They do not make instructions (beyond very, very simplistic ones). Seriously, I searched for the manual and contacted customer support -- detailed installation instructions do not existing. They are expecting an installer to do this. (2) Yep, that's a good point, most installers would have this done in around an hour and are not going to worry too much. (3). Ha, yes, part of me thought of returning it out of spite for Samsung's awful customer service. But, I already have it in place so may just make it work.

You are correct that the perimeter seals help with noise abatement.
The issue is your preference of the position of the face of the dishwasher relative to the rest of the cabinet faces.
If you want a flush appearance, you must add wood around the inside the cabinet to maintain the seal and to properly secure the dishwasher to prevent tip over. There are installation holes on the sides of the unit for this purpose.

I had this issue and used this suggestion.  I mounted wood behind the cabinet face frame for the seal to touch.

The amount the cabinet faces extend past the carcass is probably about 1/4".  If you get some 1/4" wood panels or PVC sheets (cut 'em into strips because they're probably too short for the opening height) and some 1/2" wood screws, you can screw the 1/4" filler to the inside of the cabinet, butted up against the back of the face frame.  Then push back the dishwaser as far back as you need to flush up the panel with the cabinet doors.

I agree with DelphicOracle, but I'll answer to add some other thoughts.
I've installed many dishwashers and seen them installed in many new homes. They're really never flush with cabinet face frames or door panels. They tend to be about flush with the countertop edge, but they're often proud of that, even. Here's mine.

I think manufacturers expect you to mount them far enough out so they're not difficult to load, and they know that 99% of cabinets only have that 3/4" rail to seal against. As you can see from the design of your seals, they've already extended them as far forward as is practical.
I would insert the unit until the seals are roughly centered on the depth of the face frame. See if you can live with that appearance. You should not see behind the door edge sides, as in your first photo. If it's not acceptable, take DelphicOracle's advice and add rails to the cabinet to extend the face frame rearward. With some planning you can fasten these without exposed screws.
